# How to switch to user (with password) to run a linux command with Fabric (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, fabric

I have a remote Linux server that I am trying to update a file on using a script. I need to assume user = admin in order to gain write permissions for this file.

I'm using Fabric to connect to the server, though it does not seem to be performing actions as admin.

Here is my config:

```
config = Config(overrides={'sudo': {'password': password,'user': 'admin'}})

connection = Connection(host=f'{me}@{server}',connect_kwargs={'password': password}, config=config)
```

Then I am performing these tasks (read, update, write):

```
read_file = connection.sudo(
              "bash -c 'cd /my/path/;"
              "cat my_file.dat'",
              hide=True
            )

#There is code here that adds information to my file and saves it as updated_file

connection.sudo( f"echo -e '{updated_file}' > /my/path/my_file.dat")
```

However, this is returning an error saying: `bash: /my/path/my_file.dat: Permission denied` upon trying to write the file.

*Please note that the password is stored as an external variable, and the password is the same to assume my user and the admin user. I must log in as myself before I am able to switch users to admin.

I tried:

```
connection.sudo( f"echo -e '{updated_file}' > /another/path/my_file.dat")
```

Where /another/path/ has read/write/execute permissions for all users, and this worked with no problem. However, in this directory, it showed the author of my_file.dat was me and not the admin account.

This, to me, indicates there is a configuration error where I have not assumed the admin user in my config... though I can't find anywhere that indicates there are issues with it.

I have also tried, directly on the server,

```
sudo su - admin
echo -e 'hello' > /my/path/hello.txt
```

to confirm that I can run the echo command directly.

I assume the solution is to amend the config to confirm that I actually am the admin user, or on a single command line, run the command as the admin... though I can't figure out a syntax to allow this as it requests a password.

Comment: Presumably the sudo api, calls sudo on the server, so running su as a test is irrelvant. Run the commands you sent with sudo on the server with bash to see if sudo is granting the required permissions. If not, see the /etc/sudoers file.

Comment: You could do a `id` just before the offending `echo` command, to verify under which uid the remote process runs.

Comment: @user1934428 I have added a print(connection.sudo('whoami')) before running the command. It's outputting: ===stdout === admin === stderr === [sudo] password: if that helps at all.

Comment: which part of that output comes from the `whoami` itself? Is it _admin_? Why don't you try the `id` command, i.e. `id; echo -e '{updated_file}' > /my/path/my_file.dat`?

Comment: `stderr === [sudo] password:` it seems it's asking for password